# Как подгрузить новый .class в программу в runtime?

Tags: java, classloader

Я с клавиатуры ввожу код для метода.
обновленный .java компилируется программой в .class
Как полученный .class подгрузить в программу в runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. На диске в каталоге создать структуру каталогов-пакетов, создать там class-файл. Каталог подать в `java.net.URLClassLoader` как `URL` (`File.toURI.toURL` либо `Path.toUri.toURL`).

Вариант 2. Использовать хранение class-файла в памяти как массив байт, реализовав свой `ClassLoader`, где в переопределенном методе `findClass` по нужному имени вызывать `super.defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length, this.getClass().getProtectionDomain)` и возвращать результат. Для других имен кидать `throw new ClassNotFoundException(name)`

А уже с имеющимся `ClassLoader` работать через reflection. Например, при помощи `Class.forName(name, true, classLoader)`